# Linq to xml в datatable

Tags: c#, datatable, linq2xml

Здравствуйте.Нужно вытащить данные из xml-файла. Непонятность заключается в том, что он имеет 2 уровня вложенности(не считая самого root-контейнера).
Данные оттуда нужно поместить в таблицу DataTable, но тут есть 2 уровня, значит в 2 таблицы? Сам запрос linq проблем не вызвал. А вот как теперь поместить данные в 2 таблицы для меня вопрос.. (Как обработать **el.prices**)

Код:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("products_OUT2.xml");
            var query =
                from product in doc.Root.Elements("PRODUCT")
                select new
                {
                    code = (Int32)product.Element("CODE"),
                    name = (string)product.Element("NAME"),
                    vendor = (string)product.Element("VENDOR"),
                    country = (string)product.Element("COUNTRY"),
                    vendorbarcode = (string)product.Element("VENDORBARCODE"),
                    valid_date = (DateTime)product.Element("VALID_DATE"),
                    qtty = (Int32)product.Element("QTTY"),
                    packqtty = (Int32)product.Element("PACKQTTY"),
                    prices =
                    (
                    from price in product.Elements("PRICES")
                    select new
                    {
                        area = (string)price.Element("PRICE").Attribute("area").Value,
                        prc = (double)price.Element("PRICE")
                    }
                    )
                };

            foreach (var el in query)
            {
                dt.Rows.Add(
                    el.code,
                    el.name,
                    el.vendor,
                    el.country,
                    el.vendorbarcode,
                    el.valid_date,
                    el.qtty,
                    el.packqtty,
                    el.prices = ?
                    );
            }
```

Сам xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="yes"?>
<DocumentElement>
  <PRODUCT>
    <CODE>73</CODE>
    <NAME>Бессмертника цветки 30г ф/чай </NAME>
    <VENDOR>ООО "Алтай-Фарм"</VENDOR>
    <COUNTRY>РОССИЯ</COUNTRY>
    <VENDORBARCODE>4607102610548</VENDORBARCODE>
    <VALID_DATE>2019-01-01T00:00:00+07:00</VALID_DATE>
    <QTTY>358</QTTY>
    <PACKQTTY>1</PACKQTTY>
     <PRICES>
      <PRICE area="1">78.50</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="2">78.90</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="3">82.30</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="4">86.10</PRICE>
     </PRICES>
  </PRODUCT>
  <PRODUCT>
    <CODE>76</CODE>
    <NAME>Гигрометр психрометрический ВИТ-1 (0-25 град.C)</NAME>
    <VENDOR>Стеклоприбор</VENDOR>
    <COUNTRY>УКРАИНА</COUNTRY>
    <VENDORBARCODE>9920007031665</VENDORBARCODE>
    <VALID_DATE>2025-01-01T00:00:00+07:00</VALID_DATE>
    <QTTY>166</QTTY>
    <PACKQTTY>1</PACKQTTY>
     <PRICES>
      <PRICE area="1">78.50</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="2">78.90</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="3">82.30</PRICE>
      <PRICE area="4">86.10</PRICE>
     </PRICES>
  </PRODUCT>
</DocumentElement>
```

Comment: Допустим вложить можно, а что потом? А что el.prices не вкладывается? Приведите к типу object. Инспектором посмотрите тип.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: А потом, 2 таблички легко вставить в БД SQL. Эта выборка их XML в точности соответствует моей модели данных на основе которой сгенерирована БД. Просто, как я понял linq to xml > datatable's > database самый быстрый, надежный и гибкий способ это сделать..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте две таблицы, одну для PRODUCT, другую для PRICE. Ключом в таблице PRICE будет код продукта code

```
foreach (var el in query)
{
  dt.Rows.Add(
    el.code,
    el.name,
    el.vendor,
    el.country,
    el.vendorbarcode,
    el.valid_date,
    el.qtty,
    el.packqtty
    );
  foreach (var pr in el.prices)
    dtPrice.Rows.Add(el.code, pr.area, pr.prc);
}
```

Comment: Это именно тот ответ, который я надеялся получить!!! Мне лишь не хватало "**);**" после **el.packqtty** Сделал перечисление цен ИМЕННО ВНУТРИ перечисления продуктов, но почему-то в табличке с ценами **dtPrice** выводятся только первые вхождения т.е. только первая цена для каждого товара.

Answer (score 2):

Вы сначала решите, как пользователю будет удобней смотреть и редактировать эти данные. Можно в одну таблицу всё поместить, можно в несколько.

Например, можно весь xml загрузить в `DataSet` одним методом `ReadXml`:

```
var dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.ReadXml("test.xml");
```

При этом в датасете получатся три таблицы: PRODUCT, PRICES (пустая, можно не показывать её пользователю) и PRICE (с колонками area и PRICE_text).

Выводить эти таблицы проще всего, привязывая их к `DataGridView`:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[0];
```

Если какие-то колонки не нужны, можно их скрыть; заголовки можно переименовать:

```
dataGridView.DataSource = dataSet.Tables[2];
dataGridView.Columns["area"].Visible = false;
dataGridView.Columns["PRICE_text"].HeaderText = "Price";
```

Тут проблема в том, что если пользователь прямо в `DataGridView` добавит новые строки, то при сохранении данных методом `DataSet.WriteXml` могут появиться строки совсем не там, где хотелось бы. То есть появится новая таблица. Поэтому этот способ годится только для показа данных, без их редактирования.

Comment: Понял Вас.) Данные не будут выводиться, пользователей тоже не будет, толкаю xml в datatable чтобы дальше затолкать в БД. На данном этапе мне нужно просто дублировать в своей базе данные, что 1C выгружает в xml.

Answer (score 0):

Помогли. Ниже рабочий linq-запрос к xml-файлу и вставка в 2 таблицы.

```
public void GetPricesXml(string fullpath)
    {
        var dtPRODUCTS = new DataTable();
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("CODE", typeof(Int32));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("NAME", typeof(string));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("VENDOR", typeof(string));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("COUNTRY", typeof(string));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("VENDORBARCODE", typeof(string));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("VALID_DATE", typeof(DateTime));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("QTTY", typeof(Int32));
        dtPRODUCTS.Columns.Add("PACKQTTY", typeof(Int32));
        //
        var dtPRICES = new DataTable();
        dtPRICES.Columns.Add("PRODUCTSCODE", typeof(Int32));
        dtPRICES.Columns.Add("AREASCODE", typeof(Int32));
        dtPRICES.Columns.Add("PRICE", typeof(Double));
        //-----------------------------------------------------------------
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("products_OUT2.xml");
        var query =
            from product in doc.Root.Elements("PRODUCT")
            select new
            {
                code = (Int32)product.Element("CODE"),
                name = (string)product.Element("NAME"),
                vendor = (string)product.Element("VENDOR"),
                country = (string)product.Element("COUNTRY"),
                vendorbarcode = (string)product.Element("VENDORBARCODE"),
                valid_date = (DateTime)product.Element("VALID_DATE"),
                qtty = (Int32)product.Element("QTTY"),
                packqtty = (Int32)product.Element("PACKQTTY"),
                prices = product.Element("PRICES").Descendants("PRICE").Nodes().Select(price => new {
                    area = (Int32)price.Parent.Attribute("area"),
                    prc = (Double)price.Parent
                })
            };

        foreach (var prod in query)
        {
            dtPRODUCTS.Rows.Add(
                prod.code,
                prod.name,
                prod.vendor,
                prod.country,
                prod.vendorbarcode,
                prod.valid_date,
                prod.qtty,
                prod.packqtty
                );

            foreach (var pp in prod.prices)
            {
                dtPRICES.Rows.Add(
                    prod.code,
                    pp.area,
                    pp.prc
                    );
            }
        }
    }
```